# Jmesa Toolbar - display the html.toolbar.text

Tags: toolbar, jmesa

I have a jmesa table and i want to display the html.toolbar.texts instead of the icon/images on the toolbar in run time.

I want to do that only for the navigation icons/images.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a custom export "button" so I used TextItem.
here is the code for it:

```
TextItem tItem = new TextItem();
tItem.setText("<div>" + 
            getMessageSourceAccessor().getMessage("pb.export.selected") + "</div>");
ToolbarItemRenderer renderer = new CustomItemRenderer(tItem, getCoreContext(), "selected");
renderer.setOnInvokeAction("onInvokeAction");
tItem.setToolbarItemRenderer(renderer);
addToolbarItem(tItem);
```

and here is the custom renderer:

```
public class CustomItemRenderer extends AbstractItemRenderer {
        private String type;

        public CustomItemRenderer(ToolbarItem item, CoreContext coreContext, String type) {
            setToolbarItem(item);
            setCoreContext(coreContext);
            this.type = type;
        }

        @Override
        public String render() {
            ToolbarItem item = getToolbarItem();
            String action = "javascript:jQuery.jmesa.setExportToLimit('promotions','pdf');onInvokeExportAction('promotions'," + type + ");";
            item.setAction(action);
            return item.enabled();
        }
    }
```

This is all done in my custom toolbar implementation. There might be an easier way to do it but this works for me.